# No English Abbreviation for Transcribe EE Plugin

Tags: php, plugins, expressionengine, expressionengine3

I am using Expression Engine 3 with EE Harbor Transcribe plugin.

How would I let the default language on my site (English), not require an abbreviation?

I tried leaving it blank, but then the english translation doesnt show. Right now, the only way i have it working is to us an abbreviation (en) and access it by domain.com/en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your question would be better placed at http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com but i'll try to help you here

That shouldn't be the case. Do you have english set as your default language? And do you have

```
Add language prefix to URL?
```

set to

```
defined per language
```

And in the languages tab, do you have

```
Add language prefix to URL?
```

set to

```
no
```

Comment: Thanks! I didnt have your last option set to no